# Reduce vertical size of tikz plot

Tags: pgfplots, scaling, dimensions

The following code generates a color mapped plot. I would like to reduce the vertical size however, and cannot figure out how. Can anyone give me a hint?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external,colormaps}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[enlarge x limits=false,enlarge y limits=false,
    ylabel=color of disk 1,
    xlabel=$I_l$,
    xtick={0,1,2,3},
    ytick={0,1,2,3},
    colorbar,
    colorbar style={
        yticklabels={,,}
    },
    colormap={summap}{
        color=(blue); color=(red)
    }]
    \addplot[patch,shader=interp,
    table/row sep=\\,
    patch table with individual point meta={%
        0 1 4 0 1 1\\
        1 2 4 1 1 1\\ 
        2 3 4 1 1 1\\ 
    }] table[row sep=\\] {
        x y \\ 
        0 0 \\% 0 
        1 1 \\% 1 
        3 1 \\% 2 
        3 0 \\% 3 
        1 0 \\% 4 
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Desired result:

[image]

Answer (score 51, accepted):

With explicitly adding `width=7cm,height=3cm` options to the Pgfplots axis environment you can control the size of the plot. Giving one of them will keep the aspect ratio constant hence would behave as a scaling only.

[image]

Comment: a mwe would be nice :-) for positioning is not unimportant

Comment: Irrelevant, I have forgotten a comma. There is no problem.

Answer (score 7):

Another option is to scale the entire `tikzpicture` environment. You can do this with optional arguments of `scale`, `xscale` and `yscale`. In your case you probably want `yscale`[image].

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external,colormaps}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=0.5]
\begin{axis}[enlarge x limits=false,enlarge y limits=false,
    ylabel=color of disk 1,
    xlabel=$I_l$,
    xtick={0,1,2,3},
    ytick={0,1,2,3},
    colorbar,
    colorbar style={
        yticklabels={,,}
    },
    colormap={summap}{
        color=(blue); color=(red)
    }]
    \addplot[patch,shader=interp,
    table/row sep=\\,
    patch table with individual point meta={%
        0 1 4 0 1 1\\
        1 2 4 1 1 1\\
        2 3 4 1 1 1\\
    }] table[row sep=\\] {
        x y \\
        0 0 \\% 0
        1 1 \\% 1
        3 1 \\% 2
        3 0 \\% 3
        1 0 \\% 4
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This screws up your text. Not a desired result in my opinion.

Comment: @Roald Agreed, scaling just the one axis does not work well if there is text involved but `scale=0.5` preserves the aspect ratio and so is OK in this respect, even though the text will be smaller. If there is text you can still rescale one axis in the picture using `\begin{scope}[yscale=0.5]...\end{scope}` but then the placement of the text outside of the scope-environment can be tricky, so other solutions are better.